# Hide/show MenuItem on click actionbar android

Tags: android, onclick, android-actionbar, menuitem

I've been trying to get my actionbar buttons to show on click but can't get it to work. I got 2 buttons and if i click on one i want the other to show and the other to get invinsible.
Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    MenuItem brandsMenu = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.action_brands);
    MenuItem categoryMenu = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.action_category);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_category:
            brandsMenu.setVisible(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_brands:
            categoryMenu.setVisible(true);

    }
```

This only shows errors. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call [InvalidateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) when you want to make changes to your menu.

You then use the `onCreateOptionsMenu` override to apply those changes.

Comment: If you use the support library, call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` instead

Answer (score 2):

Define  MenuItems named brandsMenu and categoryMenu and initialize them onPrepareOptionsMenu

```
categoryMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.action_category);
brandsMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.action_brands);
```

You should be able to change visibility such as `categoryMenu.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can't set visibility on menuitems.
You should invalidate the options menu and add only the menuItems you want to be visible